# Meteor #each - How to get each single item out of a variable and render it on a page?

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, meteor, each

I am using Meteor and tried to use #each, but I have a problem with it. I have some values stored in a `var` like:

```
var a = [465,77987,2132,2];
```

I wanted to render each value of `a` on HTML. I thought `#each` would be the right way to do it? Actually I don´t know how to use `#each` and the docs I found don´t really help me. I have written the following code:

JS:

```
Template.page.helpers({ 

    values: function() {
        return a;
    }
});
```

HTML:

```
{{#each values}}
    {{> page}}
{{/each}}
```

But this is obviously wrong, because I get the this Error in the client console:

> Error: {{#each}} currently only accepts arrays, cursors or falsey values.

I thought it is an array or not?

### Update

So now I have used the #each in approach, however I still get the same error-message:

> Error: {{#each}} currently only accepts arrays, cursors or falsey
> values. at badSequenceError (observe-sequence.js:183) at
> observe-sequence.js:148 at Object.Tracker.nonreactive (tracker.js:631)
> at observe-sequence.js:125 at Tracker.Computation._compute
> (tracker.js:339) at Tracker.Computation._recompute (tracker.js:358) at
> Object.Tracker._runFlush (tracker.js:523) at onGlobalMessage
> (meteor.js:401)

---

JS:

```
Template.page.helpers({ 

    values: function() {
        var a = [465,77987,2132,2]
        return a;
    }
});
```

HTML:

```
{{#each a in values }}
            {{> a}}
{{/each}}
```

### Update 2

I know now where this error comes from. I'm sorry, actually my first post was not correct. I forgot, that these values `[465,77987,2132,2]` are not directly stored in `var a`.

They are stored in a Session-Variable and `var a = Session.get('values')` and I think that´s the point why I get this error...So, I don´t think that this can work with `#each` ? Maybe I have to save it to my MongoDB first and than render it on the HTML or something like that.

Comment: Make sure your `var` is declared in the same file as your helper

Comment: Yes, good point, but I considered that.

Comment: Then you do not share enough information for people to say precisely what is your issue. We can just say that you seem to mix up templates and values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try the each/in construct:

```
{{#each value in values}}
  {{value}}
{{/each}}
```

c.f. http://blazejs.org/guide/spacebars.html#Each-in

you specified the entire template inside the each, which is what it was complaining about.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I still get the same error-message. Does it maybe makes a difference that these values [465,77987,2132,2] are derived from a XML server response and were parsed with 'new DOMparser()'.parseFromString' , than converted to numbers with parseInt and than used in JSON.stringify(values)? Because this is what happened  before. After this treatment I get this [465,77987,2132,2] and these are the numbers I would like to render on HTML.

Comment: what you describe sounds fine. can you update your question with the most recent code?

Comment: check the interior of your each loop against my code. you do not want the ">" in there.

Answer (score 1):

I'll put all the code in an example. Consider the 'import' only if you are using the recommended application structure. The files must be in the same directory. First in page.js:

```
import './page.html';

Template.page.helpers({ 
  values: function() {
    var a = [465,77987,2132,2];
    return a;
  }
});
```

Second in page.html:

```
<template name="page">
  {{#each a in values}}
    {{a}}
  {{/each}}
</template>
```